# How to render the POST results in a Django API view?

Tags: javascript, html, django, python-3.x, django-forms

I have an APIView with a get and post method with two templates called **tickets_per_day_no_results.html** and **tickets_per_day_results.html**. When I get access to the results.html file, I have two drop-down menus and a search button that I use to fetch for data from an internal web API, something like the following:.

[image: Dropdown menu]

My problem comes when I hit the search button, I end up with the results displayed as an APIView (I do not want these results, I want them to be transferred to my **tickets_per_day_results.html** file).

[image]

This is the code I have now:

**urls.py**

```
from .views import ChartData7
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),  # home
    url(r'^statistics/$', views.statistics, name="statistics"),
    url(r'^tickets_per_day_no_results/$', ChartData7.as_view()), 
]
```

**Views.py**

```
class ChartData7(APIView):

def get(self,request): 
    template_name = 'personal_website/tickets_per_day_no_results.html'
    form = DropDownMenuForm()
    return render(request, template_name, {'form': form})

def post(self,request):
    template_name = 'personal_website/tickets_per_day_results.html'
    if request.method == "POST":
        year = request.POST.get('select_year',None)
        week = request.POST.get('select_week', None)
        ....do stuff...
        data = {"label_number_days":label_number_days,
                "days_of_data": count_of_days,}
        return Reponse(data)
    return render(request, template_name)
```

**tickets_per_day_no_results**

```
{% block content %}
<h3>Please, select the year and week number to retrieve the data.</h3>
<form id="search_dates" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
<h6>Select year</h6>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <select name="select_year">
            <option value = {{form.year}}></option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <h6>Select week</h6>
        <select name="select_week">
            <option value= {{form.week}}></option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**tickets_per_day_results.html**

```
<script>
{% block jquery %}

var endpoint = '/statistics/tickets_per_day_results' //This  

var days_of_data = []
var label_number_days = []

$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: endpoint,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data)
        label_number_days = data.label_number_days
        days_of_data = data.days_of_data
        setChart()

    },
    error: function(error_data){
        console.log("error on data")
        console.log(error_data)
    }
})

{% block content %}

<div class ='row'>
<div class="col-sm-12" url-endpoint='{% url "tickets_per_day_results" %}'>
        <div>
            <canvas id="tickets_per_day" width="800" height="500"></canvas>
        </div>
</div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

My guess is that I am doing something wrong with the urls from my urls.py file or I am not sending in the correct way the tickets_per_day_results.html because in the url nav from my browser I do not see the tickets_per_day_results webpage. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Usually when using Django REST Framework, the API is called from the HTML and javascript iterates over the object returned from DRF and is displayed in the HTML. As far as I understand, instead of using Django REST Framework, use Django framework and render your results to the HTML template directly.

A simple example is shown below.

```
def homepage(request, template='homepage.html'):

    proposal_list = Proposal.objects.all().order_by('-created')

    return render_to_response(template, 
        {"proposal_list": proposal_list, },
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Instead of writing raw views, you can use [Class Based Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/) functionality of Django and render your results.